# Attempt to read property "name" on array (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Testing\resources\views\product.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm beginner in laravel, when I put stats table in blade I got this warning

> Attempt to read property "name" on array (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Testing\resources\views\product.blade.php)

This is Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $response = Http::get('https://api.lazada.co.id/rest/products/get?filter=live&app_key=100132&sign_method=sha256&timestamp=1612318435886&access_token=50000801006o5nrcA5192d1f9ag1FHQBUqffCEyCmrXDohvhzExSkczUnnxJ4y&sign=F31584775544970D59AB58EC4B1B77933BC2D32401E33C1D2D5095690C31627C');
    $data = $response->json();
    return view('product',compact ('data'));
}
```

This is view:

```
@extends('layout/main')

@section ('title', 'Testing Laravel')
@section ('container')

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
      <h1 class="mt-3">List Product</h1>
      <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Desc</th>
            <th scope="col">Brand</th>
            <th scope="col">Clothing Material</th>
            <th scope="col">Leather Material</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
        @foreach($data as $datas)
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>{{ $datas->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $datas-description }}</td>
            <td>{{ $datas->brand }}<td>
            <td>{{ $datas->clothing_material }}</td>
            <td>{{ $datas->leather_material }}</td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 
@endsection
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... your error message is so clear `Attempt to read property "name" on array`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck? Have you tried dumping `$datas` to see what it contains?

Answer (score 14):

According to the error message its clearly saying `Attempt to read property (because you are trying to access like $data->name <--OBJECT) on array` and your foreach variable is array. so you will need to access like key value pair.

Use like this in loop-

```
     {{ $data['name'] }}
     {{ $data['description'] }}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it